# How do I make a GUI appear when a specific part is touched?

Tags: roblox

```
local TDHitbox = script.Parent
local Enemy = game.Workspace.Enemy
local GUI = game.Players.LocalPlayer.ScreenGui.TextLabel

TDHitbox.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local humanoid = hit.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        GUI.TextTransparency = 0
    else
        GUI.TextTransparency = 1
    end
end)
```

This is the code I have written,I don't see any errors when I test it.But it still doesn't work

Comment: Is this a Script or a LocalScript? And where is it located?

Answer (score 0):

LocalPlayer can't be called from the server (I presume the script is located inside a part in the workspace).

You'd need to set up remote events. Read the documentation on [Remote Functions and Events](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Remote-Functions-and-Events)